# WebGoat server refuses connections from remote IP

Tags: java, tomcat, networking, owasp

I installed WebGoat on a VirtualBox Ubuntu VM. I am able to access WebGoat from localhost:8080/WebGoat/attack from the Ubuntu VM. I want to complete the challenges using a Kali Linux VM. I am able to ping Ubuntu (192.168.56.101) from Kali (Ubuntu is on host-only network, kali is bridged). When I type 192.168.56.101:8080/WebGoat/attack into kali, then it says unable to connect.  When nmapping ubuntu from localhost, then ports 8080 and 631 are up. Interestingly enough, when nmapping ubuntu from Kali, all 1000 scanned ports are down. I did iptables -L and found that all policies are set to accept.

My first thought was that either the Tomcat server or a controller in WebGoat is set to refuse remote connections. But it also seems strange that port 631 in inaccessible (I think it's only listening on localhost) How can I get a connection?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it.

WebGoat by default binds to localhost and only allows access from localhost.

You can change this by adding an additional parameter.

```
--server.address=<your_IP_address>
```

You can also change the port to 80 if you want by doing

```
--server.port=80
```

Final command to start webgoat:

```
java -jar webgoat_jar_file.jar --server.address=<your_IP_address> --server.port=80
```

Answer (score 0):

For others who came to this post and whose problem didn't resolve even using server.port and server.address parameter try the following.

**export WEBGOAT_HOST=<your_pc_hostname>**

 pc hostname can be found using hostname command in linux

then running the below command
**java -jar webgoat_jar_file.jar --server.address=<your_IP_address> --server.port=<port_you_want_server_to_run_on>**
and most important of all don't forget to add rule for the port in firewall